# How to subscribe to Spec object (TextInputField)

Tags: events, pharo

I have simple Spec object with textArea and textInputField. Next to it I have another object which Spec doesn't know about. When I write some text into textInputField i need to send message with this text to the other class. I tried announcer, but it doesn't work. Is there any way to inform other object and send it this text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are looking for `acceptBlock:` which will call a block every time the text value changes:

```
| cm |
cm := TextInputFieldPresenter new.
cm autoAccept: true.
cm acceptBlock: [ :txt | doSomething with: txt.].
```

you can find this and more about spec in the spec booklet: 
http://books.pharo.org/spec-tutorial/

note that in newer versions of pharo the spec classes have been renamed from `...Model` to `...Presenter` which is not yet reflected in the booklet. so whether you use `TextInputFieldModel` or `TextInputFieldPresenter` depends on your pharo version.